# Remove duplicate rows from joined table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following sql query

```
SELECT m.School, c.avgscore 
FROM postswithratings c 
join ZEntrycriteria on c.fk_postID= m.schoolcode
```

Which provide following result

```
School| avgscore
xyz   |  5
xyz   |  5
xyz   |  5
abc   |  3
abc   |  3
kkk   |  1
```

My question is how to remove those duplicates and get only following.

```
 School| avgscore
    xyz   |  5 
    abc   |  3
    kkk   |  1
```

I tried with

```
   SELECT m.School, c.avgscore 
   FROM postswithratings c 
   join ZEntrycriteria on c.fk_postID= m.schoolcode 
   group by m.School
```

But it gives me following error

> "Column 'postswithratings.avgscore' is invalid in the select list
>   because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the
>   GROUP BY clause."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to make things complicated.  Just go with:

```
SELECT m.School, c.avgscore 
FROM postswithratings c 
join ZEntrycriteria on c.fk_postID= m.schoolcode 
group by m.School, c.avgscore
```

or

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.School, c.avgscore 
FROM postswithratings c 
join ZEntrycriteria on c.fk_postID= m.schoolcode
```

Comment: just by adding SELECT DISTINCT it worked.. Thank you. +1

Answer (score 1):

You have to only add distinct keyword like this :-

```
 SELECT DISTINCT  m.School, c.avgscore 
  FROM postswithratings c 
 join ZEntrycriteria on c.fk_postID= m.schoolcode
```

Answer (score 0):

This will delete the Duplicate rows (Only Duplicate)

**Schema:**

```
CREATE TABLE #TAB (School varchar(5) , avgscore int)
INSERT INTO #TAB
SELECT 'xyz', 5
UNION ALL
SELECT 'xyz', 5
UNION ALL
SELECT 'xyz', 5
UNION ALL
SELECT 'abc', 3
UNION ALL
SELECT 'abc', 3
UNION ALL
SELECT 'kkk', 1
```

Now use CTE as your Tempprary View and delete the data.

```
;WITH CTE AS(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY School,avgscore  ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) DUP_C, 
School,  avgscore FROM #TAB
)

DELETE FROM CTE WHERE DUP_C>1
```

Now do check #TAB, the data will be

```
+--------+----------+
| School | avgscore |
+--------+----------+
| xyz    |        5 |
| abc    |        3 |
| kkk    |        1 |
+--------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #Table2
    ([School] varchar(3), [avgscore] int)

INSERT INTO #Table2
    ([School], [avgscore])
VALUES
    ('xyz', 5),
    ('xyz', 5),
    ('xyz', 5),
    ('abc', 3),
    ('abc', 3),
    ('kkk', 1)
;
SELECT  SCHOOL,AVGSCORE FROM (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY [AVGSCORE] ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RN FROM #TABLE2)A
WHERE RN=1
ORDER BY AVGSCORE
-------
;WITH CTE AS
(SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY [AVGSCORE] ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RN FROM #TABLE2)
SELECT SCHOOL,AVGSCORE  FROM CTE WHERE RN=1
```

output

```
SCHOOL  AVGSCORE
kkk      1
abc      3
xyz      5
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the DISTINCT keyword will make sql use sets instead of multisets. So values only appear once

Answer (score 0):

you only use group by if you're using aggregated function, eg. max. sum, avg

in that case,

```
SELECT Distinct(m.School), c.avgscore 
FROM postswithratings c 
join ZEntrycriteria on c.fk_postID= m.schoolcode
```